# netbeans: dependencies for c3p0 and hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, netbeans, dependencies

Are these the correct dependencies for a hibernate and c3p0 JavaSE application?  My `pom.xml` currently:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>crud</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>unknown-jars-temp-repo</id>
            <name>A temporary repository created by NetBeans for libraries and jars it could not identify. Please replace the dependencies in this repository with correct ones and delete this repository.</name>
            <url>file:${project.basedir}/lib</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.8.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>unknown.binary</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final</artifactId>
            <version>SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>unknown.binary</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java-5.1.23-bin</artifactId>
            <version>SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>c3p0</groupId>
            <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
</project>
```

This is from netbeans, and I'm not quite clear on what to click on, even after referencing the Netbeans guide on maven.

Does this meet the hibernate and c3p0 requirements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

these dependencies were added by the IDE via the Library mechanism (Tools/Library Manager) and proper Maven GAV (GroupID-ArtifactID-version) could not be recognized (there are several strategies but apparently all failed). The generated pom snippet is the fallback that tries to make it all work for you locally. Ideally you would manually replace that with the proper GAV from a public repository.